# Non-retryable error has occurred

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Hoping to get some support from Microsoft on this one: we recently launched  an integration with OneDrive using the Microsoft Graph API at my company and have been somewhat frequently been getting this error upon authorization with the business/SharePoint versions of OneDrive:

```
error: 'temporarily_unavailable'
error_description: 'AADSTS70012: Non-retryable error has occurred.
Trace ID: a7585d82-3b6d-4552-af1f-0ce32ffc2300
Correlation ID: 4913d1c5-580d-46ce-bbbc-a28e95d7ae37
Timestamp: 2017-09-05 19:03:38Z'
```

This error appears to be on Microsoft's end (though perhaps it is not), was hoping to get some insight as to why this is happening to our users so frequently upon authorization and how it can be avoided. Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about how you're authorizing users and when in the process this error occurs?

Comment: We're utilizing the OAuth 2.0 flow as described [here](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/graph_oauth.htm). 

The error is shown on our server at the point in time after the OneDrive.open callback is executed, after the sign in screen where the user selects the Microsoft account they wish to authorize with the given application that's requesting permission, but before the given application is actually given permission. From my experience, it seems to happen more frequently with OneDrive for Business than it does with OneDrive personal.

Comment: Thank you. Which scopes are you selecting?

Comment: offline_access Files.Read Sites.Read.All Files.Read.All

Comment: Is this happening across an entire tenant or just some users within a given tenant? Also, is there a reason why you're going through the OAUTH flow separately rather than allowing the OneDrive File Picker SDK to handle it for you?

Comment: As of today (possibly slightly earlier), it has been happening across all instance of OneDrive for Business authentication. I believe the reason that we're not using the SDK access token is either because we weren't aware of it. Does that allow for token refresh as well? Looking at the docs, there is not a refresh token provided in the response object of the SDK request.

Comment: Update: this error seems to have returned to a highly intermittent state (not happening consistently across OneDrive for Business authentication). Still wondering if it's possible to avoid it entirely, perhaps utilizing the access token that is returned with the SDK file picker is the answer.